# PHP em tempo real

Tags: php, html5

Me deparei com uma situação que pra mim é complexa.
Como fazer a atualização de um conteúdo em uma página HTML sem precisar atualizar a página, sempre que o banco de dados for alterado, os dados são modificados sem dar refresh neles. Apenas aparece os novos dados.
Procurei por Ajax, mas alguns amigos disseram que ele sobrecarrega o servidor quando tem muitos usuários.
PHP long Polling, até cheio perto de implementar ele, mas não ficou da forma como queria. É como se fosse a aba de comentários do Facebook, quando um novo comentário é enviado, ele só aparece na página, sem atualizar o conteúdo ou a página. Não quero códigos feitos. Quero respostas de métodos pra fazer isso, os prós e contras, alguém por aí já usou ou usa isso? Pode usar como comparação do que preciso, as funcionalidades em tempo real desse site mesmo. Stack Overflow.

Comment: É exatamente o Ajax. Não é que ele sobrecarrega o servidor, é que seriam N consultas de tempos em tempos, até porque o Ajax é client-side, ou seja, demanda do processamento do client, mas no seu caso faz requisições no banco de dados (servidor).

Comment: @rbz, o StackOverflow não utiliza ajax para isso. Utiliza WebSockets.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Eu quis mais comentar no contexto que ele havia passado. Mas também não sabia que o SO usava isso. Rs